# Using database data in my javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

i'm working on a project where I want to create a visual chart with some data that's stored in my mysql database.

Below you can see my phpcode to fetch the data from the database.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tbldiary` ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
// get data and store in a json array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $orders[] = array(
        'Datum' => $row['di_datum'],
        'Gevoel' => $row['di_gevoel']
      );
}

echo json_encode($orders);

?>
```

Now this is my javascript code for making a chart

```
$(function() {

            var bar_data = {
                data: [["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9]],
                color: "#3c8dbc"
            };
            $.plot("#bar-chart", [bar_data], {
                grid: {
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#f3f3f3",
                    tickColor: "#f3f3f3"
                },
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.5,
                        align: "center"
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "categories",
                    tickLength: 0
                }
            });
            /* END BAR CHART */
        });
```

So what I basically want is implement data from my mysql to my javascript function.
So the months January, February,.. needs to be replaces by the data from `row['di_datum']` and the numbers needs to be replaces by the data from `row['di_gevoel']`

Comment: How about printing the data into the <script>.

Comment: What does the output of your JSON look like after json_encode?

Comment: [{"Datum":"2014-04-26","Gevoel":"5"},{"Datum":"2014-04-28","Gevoel":"10"},{"Datum":"2014-04-28","Gevoel":"-5"},{"Datum":"2014-04-28","Gevoel":"5"}]

Comment: Ok, you have an array of objects produced from an associative array here. Your charting plugin expects an array of arrays, so you need to do a little data transformation of the AJAX response to get it to work with your plugin. See my updated answer below. It should provide the correct assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make an AJAX request and then map the results, you can use it in your $.plot plugin:

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/data',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET'
        }).done(function(data) {
            var plotData = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                plotData.push([data[i].Datum, parseInt(data[i].Gevoel)]); 

            var bar_data = {
                data: plotData,
                color: "#3c8dbc"
            };

            $.plot("#bar-chart", [bar_data], {
                grid: {
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#f3f3f3",
                    tickColor: "#f3f3f3"
                },
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.5,
                        align: "center"
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "categories",
                    tickLength: 0
                }
            });
        /* END BAR CHART */
    }); 
});
```

When your AJAX request is successful, it enters the `done` method and you have access to your response from the callback parameter, data. The variable, plotData, is just initialized as an empty array and the for loop fills the array.

The data returned from your AJAX request needs to be in the same name/value pair as the data in your example.

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. Do I need to fill in var plotData = [];?

Comment: I updated my answer. You don't fill in plotData manually. The for loop takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to use AJAX? How about this solution which directly puts your queried mySQL data into the Javscript:

```
$(function() {
            var bar_data = {
                data: '<?=json_encode($orders,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);?>',
                color: "#3c8dbc"
            };
```